# What is the value of $1^z$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%5E%28x%2Biy%29), $1^z=1$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$. If this is true, then what is wrong with the following argument that $1^z$ has infinitely many values?

Let $z=x+iy$. Then,
\begin{align}
1^z &= 1^{x+iy} \\
&= 1^x \cdot 1^{iy} \\
&= 1^{iy} \\
&= e^{iy\log(1)} \\
\log(1) &= \{0,2i \pi, 4i \pi,6i \pi, \ldots\} \\
1^z &= \{e^{iy \cdot 0},e^{iy \cdot 2 i \pi},e^{iy \cdot 4 i \pi},e^{iy \cdot 6 i \pi},\ldots\} \\
&= \{e^0,e^{-2y\pi},e^{-4y\pi},e^{-6y\pi},\ldots\}
\end{align}

Only one of these values is equal to $1$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha is not God so take its answers in context, not as eternal truths of mathematics; in particular, you are right that $1^z$ is (in general) an infinite set of which $1$ is a distinguished value

Comment: Why does this need explaining?

Comment: @Jakobian because for some people Wolfram Alpha is God whose answers are eternally true

Comment: @Conrad Thou shall not question the infinite wisdom of WolframAlpha ;)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I am still waiting for the Beta version... :)

Comment: If you define $\log$ as a function, we have to pick a single value of $\log 1,$ and we’ll usually choose the value $0.$ If you have $\log$ as a multi valued function, then you are correct, $w^z$ is multi-valued, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, when $a>0$, you define $a^z$ as $\exp\bigl(z\log(a)\bigr)$, where $\log(a)$ is the only real logarithm of $a$, then indeed we always have $1^z=1$.

Otherwise, it's up to you to tell us *how* you are defining $1^z$. However, note that the set of all logarithms of $1$ is *not* $\{0,2\pi i,4\pi,i,6\pi i,\ldots\}$; it's $\{0,\pm2\pi i,\pm4\pi i,\pm6\pi i,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that you once answered a question about a fake proof about why $re^{i\theta}=r$: $$re^{i\theta} = re^{(2 \pi i \theta)/2\pi} = r(e^{2\pi i})^{\theta /2\pi} = r(1)^{\theta/2\pi} = r \, .$$
Is the problem the same as the one here: $e^z$ is a function; but $(e^{2\pi i})^z=1^z$ is not a function if we define $z^w$ as $\exp(w\log(z))$?

Comment: No; it has something to do with it, but it's not the same thing. Here, we have a problem of defining the meaning of the expressions that we are using. I provided in my answer the more usual meaning of the expression $a^z$, when $z\in\Bbb C$ and $a\in(0,\infty)$. According to that definition, $1^z$ is indeed $1$, for every $z\in\Bbb C$. If you are using some other definition of $1^z$, then you should tell us which definition you have in mind.

Comment: I wasn't aware that $a^z$ could have more than one definition if $a$ is a real number. Thank you for clearing up my confusion. In your experience, when people write $e^z$, is this generally just a shorthand for $\exp(z)$? Because if we interpret $e^z$ as $\exp(z\log(e))$, where $\log$ is the complex logarithm, then it would seem that $e^z$ is a multi-valued function.

Comment: In my experience, *every single time* that someone writes $e^z$, what that means is $\exp(z)$. However, concerning $\exp(z\log(e))$, note that I wrote in my answer that I was dealing with the only real logarithm of $a$. In this case, $a=e$, and its only real logarithm is $1$. So, $\exp(z\log(e))=\exp(z)$.

Comment: Going back to the fake proof: you say that the problem is that in general $e^{ab} \neq (e^a)^b$. In the context of the fake proof, you appear to be saying that $re^{(2 \pi i \theta)/2\pi} \neq r(e^{2\pi i})^{\theta /2\pi}$. Is it possible if you elaborate on what the problem is here?

Comment: Actually, what I claim is that the equality $e^{ab}=(e^a)^b$ doesn't make sense, since $(e^a)^b$ is undefined, in general.

Comment: Why is $(e^a)^b$ undefined in general? Couldn't it be interpreted as $\exp(b\log(e^a))$? Is the problem with the meaning of $\log(e^a)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117896/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-joe).

Comment: I responded to you in chat, by the way. If you have the time to explain this a little more, I'd be very grateful. But I understand if this is not possible. In any case, thank you for explaining this to me.